# How to add pandas data to an existing csv file in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-cloud-storage

I'm saving files to a csv on my google cloud storage using pandas. The problem is that my file gets overwritten when I rewrite data.

```
    url = gs://mybucket/my.csv
    df.to_csv(url,mode="a", index=False, header=False)
```

I have however specified the writing mode to "a" to add afterwards without rewriting the file.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage objects are immutable. This means you cannot modify an object once created. You must implement read-modify-write and replace the existing object.

[Object immutability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability)

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
> change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
> is the time between successful object creation, such as uploading, and
> successful object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot
> make incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or
> truncate operations. However, it is possible to replace objects that
> are stored in Cloud Storage, and doing so happens atomically: until
> the new upload completes, the old version of the object is served to
> readers, and after the upload completes the new version of the object
> is served to readers. So a single replacement operation simply marks
> the end of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of a new
> immutable object's lifetime.

Google also supports the Compose API. This supports combining two or more objects to result in a new Cloud Storage object.

[Composing Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composing-objects)

With the Compose API, you could upload the **append** data to a temporary object, then combine the original object with the append object. This would emulate appending to a file.